# Homepage Menu Link Won't Function

Tags: menus, multisite, javascript

I am fairly new to Wordpress. I have been setting up sites using a template in a multisite installation. On the home page, one of the links "Twin Tiers Saves" is unresponsive but it shows in the bottom left corner of the page without the "http://" necessary for navigation. The link should open a new tab but when I click it nothing happens. The link works on all other pages except the homepage. The site is here: https://capcityradio.net/staging/. Does anyone have any advice on how to get this menu item functioning correctly? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is the menu link "Twin Tier Saves". I have narrowed it down to line #1985 in the jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp file. I am new to wordpress so any help that you can give is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function in `/themes/lucid-press-child/js/custom-js.js` is your problem.

```
function homepageNavigationClasses(){
    if(jQuery('body.home').length){
        //jQuery('#navigation a').not('.sub-menu a').click(function(event){
        jQuery('#navigation a').click(function(event){

            var clickedLink = jQuery(this).text();
            clickedLink = clickedLink.replace(/\s/g,'');


            if(!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('page')){
                event.preventDefault();
                //console.log(clickedLink);
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery("#"+clickedLink).offset().top - 400
                }, 500);

                jQuery('#navigation li').removeClass('active-hp-section');
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active-hp-section');
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

It's looking for a ID to scroll the page too but it doesn't have one because its an external link.

You could create a child theme and re-write the function.  But the following solution is probably simpler.

Go to `Admin > Appearance > Customize > Menus` and manually add the `page` class to the "CSS Classes" field.  This will add the class to the list item of the link and now your link will function as normal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much....I am very new to this so please forgive me as I am attempting to move into wordpress/web dev from mostly c# and python. Following your instructions, I get to the menu area but I am not sure how to add a class. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Did you add the "Twin Tiers Saves" link in through the customizer menu?  If so you should be able to add a class.  See the image I added to my answer.  If you didn't add the link that way, how did you add it?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I wish I could see you in person and hand you money in your hand. You just saved my life. Good karma will definitely be returned your way. Thank you again